# Raspistill picture washed out or complete green in direct sunlight

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspistill

I've create a script to take pictures periodically using my Raspberry Pi Zero W and a camera module.  The script works, but I find the exposure lacking.  In sunlight, the pictures are washed out or completely green.

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=$[$(cat /home/dacracot/pix/sequence) + 1]
SEQ=$(printf "%04d" $COUNTER)
echo $COUNTER > /home/dacracot/pix/sequence
raspistill -rot 90 -o /home/dacracot/pix/shots/shot-$SEQ.gif --encoding gif --nopreview --exposure sports --timeout 1
```

Is there a command line switch to handle extreme lighting situations beyond the --exposure?

Comment: How about sharing the image so we can try analysing it? Have you tried getting `raspistill` to give you the raw image so it can be processed better? `GIF` is not a very good choice of format for photos, btw.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Why is GIF a bad choice?

Comment: It can only store 256 colours vs JPEG's 16million, and it compresses poorly unless storing large areas of solid colour such as computer-generated graphics. On an empirical level, I don't believe there is a single camera on the market that defaults to storing photos in GIF - nearly all use JPEG, RAW or DNG.